# JSON response array dictionary swift3 alamofire SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON in my project. I've got a  JSON response like the one below. I want to populate a tableview with sections with the following titles: "Students Male","Students Female","Leaders Male","Leaders Female" etc, with name and age in the row under the title.

Here the leaders female is empty so that section should not be displayed

```
[
  {
    "students": {
      "male": [
        {
          "name": "rahul",
          "age": "11"
        },
        {
          "name": "raj",
          "age": "8"
        }
      ],
      "female": [
          "name": "neha",
          "age": "9"
      ]
    },
    "leaders": {
      "male": [
        {
          "name": "john",
          "age": "15"
        }
      ],
      "female": []
    },
    "manager": {
      "branchA": [],
      "branchB": []
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: post what have you tried, your question seems a homework to me, have you get the answer from your server already?

Comment: Also, `json["students"]["female"]` is invalid. If it's an array it should contain objects (like `json["students"]["male"]`)